# How to cap and round number in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to "cap" a number in Ruby (on Rails).

For instance, I have, as a result of a function, a float but I need an int.

I have very specific instructions, here are some examples:

If I get `1.5` I want `2` but if I get `2.0` I want `2` (and not `3`)

Doing `number.round(0) + 1` won't work.

I could write a function to do this but I am sure one already exists.

If, nevertheless, it does not exist, where should I create my cap function?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try [ceil](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_float.html#Float.ceil):

```
 1.5.ceil => 2
 2.0.ceil => 2
```

Comment: 1.1.ceil => 2   (another example)

Answer (score 11):

How about `number.ceil`?

This returns the smallest Integer greater than or equal to number.

Be careful if you are using this with negative numbers, make sure it does what you expect:

```
1.5.ceil      #=> 2
2.0.ceil      #=> 2
(-1.5).ceil   #=> -1
(-2.0).ceil   #=> -2
```

Answer (score 11):

.ceil is good, but remember, even smallest value in float will cause this:

```
a = 17.00000000000002
17.0
a.ceil
18
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [Numeric#ceil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Numeric.html#M000577):

```
irb(main):001:0> 1.5.ceil
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> 2.0.ceil
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> 1.ceil
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

[float.ceil](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref%5Fc%5Ffloat.html) is what you want for positive numbers.  Be sure to consider the behavior for negative numbers.  That is, do you want -1.5 to "cap" to -1 or -2?